# doOnCancel() not triggered on calling StreamController#close()

Tags: flutter, dart, rxdart

I'm passing `Observable` stream **(rxDart)** to `StreamBuilder` in order to listen and update the UI, and after that when I'm closing the stream in `onDispose()`. I expected that closing stream will trigger `doOnClose()` side effect of my observable but unfortunately the `doOnClose()` of Observable not getting called,

What I'm doing is:

```
Observable<dynamic> observerStream() {
    return Observable.fromFuture(someFunction())
      return data;
    })
    .doOnCancel(() {
        print('*** NOT GETTING CALLED ***');  
    })
.asBroadcastStream();
```

Inside the Widget

```
StreamController _controller = StreamController<dynamic>();

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _controller?.addStream(observerStream());
}

return StreamBuilder(
  stream: _controller.stream,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    return body(snapshot.data);
  },
);

@override
void dispose() { 
  _controller?.close();
  super.dispose();
}
```

As per above code `doOnClose()` should called but it's not getting called!!!

Any idea about this kind of behaviour or scenario?

Answer (score 0):

`.asBroadcastStream` requires the developer to explicitly handle the case of no more listeners - such as `.asBroadcastStream( onCancel: (sub) => sub.cancel() )`.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/60470366/8696915 for more info.