# Dart stream .asBroadcastStream memory leak

Tags: dart, stream, rxdart

In our Flutter application we have memory leaks and streams not being closed. We traced the source to code such as:

`Rx.combineLatest(...).asBroadcastStream()`

The result of RxDart `.combineLatest()` is a single-subscription stream. Adding `.asBroadcastStream()` makes the stream conveniently available to our various Flutter displays. However when these displays are closed the streams being combined are still active.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the `.asBroadcastStream()` documentation:

> The returned stream will subscribe to this stream when its first subscriber is added, and **will stay subscribed until this stream ends, or a callback cancels the subscription**.

So by design the stream exists until explicitly cancelled. To cancel the subscription when the last listener cancels use:

`Rx.combineLatest(...).asBroadcastStream( onCancel: (sub) => sub.cancel() )`

There is further discussion in [Stream.asBroadcastStream - Easy to cause leaks, what is the rationale? #26686](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/26686)